# JavaFX - Add space between buttons via CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am trying to add some space between buttons in JavaFX using CSS.
I know that separator element can do that, but I prefer to use it to separate logical groups of buttons.

I have tried:

```xml
<HBox id="buttonPanel" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="buttonPanel" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.chart.buttons.ButtonPanelController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@buttonpanel.css"/>
    </stylesheets>

    <Button text="INSTRUMENT"/>
    <Separator/>        
    <Button text="F"/>
    <Button text="T"/>
    <Button text="SR"/>
    <Separator/>

</HBox>
```

```css
.buttonPanel .button {

    -fx-spacing: 5;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-padding: 1 2 1 2;   /* Top Right Bottom Left */

}
```

But I do not get any result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give an ID then try `#`

```
#buttonPanel {
  -fx-spacing: 5;
  -fx-border-width: 0;
  -fx-padding: 1 2 1 2;   /* Top Right Bottom Left */
}
```

Comment: see answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I did this:

```css
.buttonPanel {

    -fx-spacing: 5;

}
```

Spacing seems that needs to be applied to the container, not to the buttons themselves.

Comment: Note this works because you gave the `HBox` both an ID and a style class of `buttonPanel`. If you didn't also add a style class you would need to use the syntax shown by Raw's answer.